# I have javascript function that add numbers to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have javascript function that add numbers to array  start form min to max and increase by step but when  I use getNumbers(2, 20, 2);  it print 2,22,222,2222,.... It doesn't increase can anyone help me please.

```
        function getNumbers(min, max, step) {
               var i;
              for(i=min ; i<max ; i+=step){
               array.push(i);
               alert(array);
            }
```

Comment: Make sure your arguments are numbers, not strings.

Comment: yes if you will give arguments as strings then this problem will come, because the statement `i+=step` so `"2"+="2"` will return `22` after that `222` and so on.

Comment: can you just add a fiddle with your prolem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your function, you must pass numbers, if the passing parameters are string, change them to numbers as i did below:

```
var array = new Array();
function getNumbers (min, max, step) {
              var i;
              for(i=min ; i<max ; i+=step){
               array.push(i);
               alert(array);
              }
}
//passing numbers:
getNumbers(1, 10, 2);
//output is 1,3,5,7,9

//if your numbers are strings, use:
var min = '1';
var max = '10';
var step = '2';
getNumbers(parseInt(min), parseInt(max), parseInt(step));
//this will work correctly
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qx63x73z/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` to cast to integers

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the function. Other than the array is not defined.

You're probably sending the variables in as a string, which causes concatenation instead of addition.

```
function getNumbers(min, max, step) {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = min ; i <= max ; i += step){
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

You might also need to make sure that you use `i <= max` in your loop, if you want to include the max.